# Is it possible to set GPU affinity for a mixed precision NN, with FP32 and FP16 going to different GPUs?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, nvidia

I have a GTX 1080 and an RTX 2080. I want to train using both, but since the RTX can handle FP16 twice as fast, I'd like to set it up so that the training is multi-GPU and the RTX handles the FP16 layers and the GTX handles the FP32 layers.

Is this possible under tensorflow, pytorch, or keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tensorflow

In TF, it is possible to specify for each layer on which device to be executed (GPU, CPU, or specific GPU if you have multiple GPUs ...). This is done using `with tf.device('device_name')` statement (you need to provide meaningful `device_name`). See [Using multiple GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#using_multiple_gpus) section.

### Keras

Since this is possible in TF, that means that you can use it also in Keras, if you use TF as Keras backend (Keras is just a high-level neural networks API).

Note that in Keras there is a `multi_gpu_model()` function in Keras, but that only copies a whole model on multiple GPUs, you cannot specify which layer to put on specific GPU.